# Using regex in bash scripting

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to use regex in an if statement in a bash script, but I am getting different values.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="input2.txt"

paramCheck(){
  while read -r line; do
    d=( $line )
    e=${d[@]:1}
    for i in "$e"; do
      if [ "$i" == $[st][0-9] ]; then
         echo "$i"
      fi
    done
  done < "$a"
}

echo `paramCheck`
```

The text file:

```
add $s1 $s2 $s3
sub $t0 
sub $t1 $t0 
addi $t1 $t0 $s5
```

The predicted results:

```
$s1 $s2 $s3 $t0 $t1 $t0 $t1 $t0 $s5
```

The actual result was: nothing printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double brackets for regex matching and escape the dollar, as it is a special bash character. Substitute

`if [ "$i" == $[st][0-9] ]; then`

for

`if [[ "$i" = \$[st][0-9] ]]; then`

Comment: `[[ = ]]` uses wildcard ("glob") pattern syntax, not regular expressions. For regular expression matching, use `[[ =~ ]]'` instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson maybe you're right, but why this works then? I'm not using wildcards.

Comment: Both glob patterns and RE use `[]` character classes, but otherwise they're quite a bit different. For instance, in an RE, "`?`" means "the last thing is optional", but in a glob it means "any single character" (in an RE, you'd use "`.`" for that). In an RE, "`*`" means "zero or more of the last thing", but in a glob it means "any string of zero or more characters" (in an RE, you'd use "`.*`" for that). (And of course, there are multiple variations of both glob and RE syntax...) Another difference here is that `[[ = ]]` must match the whole string, but `[[ =~ ]]` allows substring matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do this using various standard utilities:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2- infile | grep -o '\$[st][[:digit:]]' | paste -sd ' '
$s1 $s2 $s3 $t0 $t1 $t0 $t1 $t0 $s
```

- `cut` removes the first space separated column
- `grep` finds all matches of the pattern and prints them one per line
- `paste` gets the output on a single line

---

In pure Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -ra line; do
    for word in "${line[@]:1}"; do
        [[ $word == \$[st][[:digit:]] ]] && printf '%s ' "$word"
    done
done < 'input2.txt'
```

- reads directly into an array with `read -a`
- no intermediate assignment, loop directly over elements of `"${line[@]:1}"`
- use `[[ ]]` for pattern matching, escape `$`, use locale-safe `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`
- use `printf` instead of `echo` to suppress linebreaks

Notice that this'll add a trailing blank.

---

A few pointers for your code:

- `d=( $line )` relies on word splitting and is subject to filename expansion; if you have a word `*` in `$line`, it'll expand to all files in the directory.
- `e=${d[@]:1}` assigns the second and later elements of the array to a single string – now we don't have an array any longer. To keep the array, use `e=("${d[@]:1}")` instead.
- `for i in "$e"` now has `$e` containing all the elements in a single string, and the quoting suppresses word splitting, so for the first line, this'll put all of `$s1 $s2 $s3` into `i` instead of just `$s1`. The intent is probably `for i in $e`, but that's again subject to word splitting and glob expansion; use an array instead.
- `[ ]` doesn't support pattern matching, use `[[ ]]` instead. `$` has to be escaped.
- Glob patterns (used here) are *not* regular expressions. Check the "Patterns" article in the references for a good overview of the differences.
- Bash does understand both `==` and `=` within `[ ]`, but `==` isn't portable (as in "POSIX conformant") – it's a good habit to use `=` instead. Within `[[ ]]`, it's debatable what to use, as `[[ ]]` isn't portable itself.
- `` echo `cmd` `` is the same as just `cmd`.

---

References:

- [`cut` invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#cut-invocation)
- [`grep -o` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002do)
- [`paste` invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html#paste-invocation)
- [Wooledge wiki article about patterns](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns)